# How to use Postgres sequence with JPA?

Tags: postgresql, jpa

I have a 'customer' table in my postgresql database with a particular field: `cus_number` which has a sequence defined. This field is not the primary key, there's already an `cus_id` field.

The default value of the cus_number is

```
nextval('customer_cus_number_seq'::regclass) it's the sequence.
```

With pgadmin, when I insert a row in this customer table with a null value as the `cus_number` it works fine and the default value sequence is used.
But in my webap, when I persist a new Customer(), the row inserted has nothing in the field `cus_number`.

Here is my custom entity definition :

```
public class Customer implements Serializable {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "pers_id")
private Integer id;

...

@Column(name = "cus_number")
private Integer number;

...
```

}

And the sequence script :

```
  CREATE SEQUENCE customer_cus_number_seq
  INCREMENT 1
  MINVALUE 100
  MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
  START 114
  CACHE 1;
```

ALTER TABLE customer_cus_number_seq
  OWNER TO fizzconsulting;

Do you some tips for me please ?

Thanks.

Comment: "*when I insert a row in this customer table with a null value as the cus_number it works*" - no it doesn't. If you supply a `NULL` value, a `NULL` value will be stored. The default clause is only used when the column is not mentioned in the column list of the `insert` statement (that's something different than supplying a `NULL` value)

Comment: Yes you are right !, and this explain why the default value (sequence) is set when doing insert withouth cus_number. But with JPA how can I avoid to set a null value when persist a customer entity ?

Comment: You created a sequence. `GenerationType.IDENTITY` is for a different purpose (for an auto-increment column). You need a `@SequenceGenerator` something along the lines above  the field `private Integer id;` `@SequenceGenerator(name = "customerIdSequence", sequenceName = "customer_cus_number_seq", allocationSize=1, initialValue=1)` and then refer to this sequence using `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "customerIdSequence")`. Disclaimer to the statement : I do not use PostgreSQL but it should conceptually be the same as Oracle which I had been using in the past.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Or an explicit `DEFAULT` keyword is provided, but few apps and tools seem to support that :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok Here's the solution :

For allowing the database default value of this fields (which is the nextval of the sequence cus_number_seq) JPA has to not reference the cus_number value while persisting transaction. To do this just annotate @Column(name = "cus_number", insertable = false)
This way the field is not mentionned while inserting a new customer, so the default value nextval sequence used DB side.

it works fine now.
Thanks for your tips.

Comment: With this approach the insert works, but the value generated by the sequence is not returned by the insert query. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

@Tiny, is next is the right definition ?

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@SequenceGenerator(name = "customerNumberSequence", sequenceName = "customer_cus_number_seq", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 100)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "pers_id")                                                                       
private Integer id;
...
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "customerNumberSequence")
@Column(name = "cus_number")
private Integer number;
...
```

JPA seems to not accept this declaration :
Exception Description: Class [class tfe.entity.Customer] has two @GeneratedValues: for fields [customer.cus_number] and [customer.pers_id]. Only one is allowed.

Thanks.

Comment: Why have you got IDENTITY in there still? you say you're using a sequence, so use SEQUENCE. Why are you putting SEQUENCE on "number" field now? it should go on "id"